# how to protect a personal computer?

Tags: linux, attack-prevention

I am Linux user with no knowledge on security , up to now i dont know that is my system was in attack or not . I havent felt anything wrong with my system . but every Computer user must have some knowledge on basic system security . so what are the basic things/methods i need to follow the check the security of system and to protect it .

Comment: That is far, far too broad for us to answer here. For something that vague, I suggest looking at past questions about good books on the site and then asking us specific questions as you go through the material and need more understanding than the book you've chosen is providing.

Comment: what precautions have to take by a basic user ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be interested in a Linux hardening guide. There are copious amounts of articles online which cover how to secure your operating system. Here are a few:

http://www.gotroot.com/Linux+Hardening+Guide
http://www.puschitz.com/SecuringLinux.shtml
http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-security.html

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Jeff, your post is much to vague to receive any kind of constructive information. Are you a system administrator or are you trying to secure a personal Linux machine? Is this a server or a workstation?

I suggest doing a little google'ing and seeing what comes up. I suggest checking out these sites for starters:
http://library.linode.com/security/basics
http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Security-HOWTO/

Comment: Hi I am just a Linux user but with no knowledge on security and not a system admin . thank for the links .